# Swift: Understanding Outlet linkage

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

Using the Interface Builder in XCode we control drag from a textfield to the view controller Swift class resulting in this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
```

Now I know that this field links to a specific text field on the storyboard.  But how do you look at the this code and determine which textfield this `nameTextField` attribute refers to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the editor's gutter there is a grey dot. Click on that and it will give you a link to the storyboard.

[image: The grey dot]
[image: Link to the storyboard screenshot]

If you want to see all of the connections from Interface Builder:

1. Click on a yellow box for the view controller in IB
2. Open the Connections Inspector in the right-most box
3. You'll be able to see all of the connected IBOutlets (you can also hover over one and the view will be highlighted).

[image: Screenshot of viewing IBOutlets]

Answer (score 2):

> But how do you look at the this code

There is no code beyond what you cited:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
```

The trick is that the name `"nameTextField"` is also written into the nib file. At runtime, the nib file is loaded and this string is used via *key–value coding* to match up with the `nameTextField` property in the nib file's owner (here, the view controller), and the text field instantiated by the loading of the nib is *assigned* to that property.

Comment: The process is described in full, in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections